# Effect of GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8 on texture interpolation?

Tags: opengl, textures, interpolation

OpenGL allows one to declare a texture as being in sRGB (as images typically are) by using `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8`, which will cause OpenGL to convert the sRGB colors to linear RGB space when sampling the texture in GLSL. This is also known as "Gamma Correction".

I've also read that linear interpolation in textures will behave differently with `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` as interpolation will supposedly happen in linear space aswell. What effect, if any, does this have? Does this mean that one should always use `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` for textures, rather than doing one's own sRGB -> linear conversion via GLSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a side note, this is what the [OpenGL 4.5 core profile specification](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf) has to say about this (quoting from section "8.24 sRGB Texture Color Conversion"):

> Ideally, implementations should perform
>   this color conversion on each sample prior to filtering but
>   implementations are allowed
>   to perform this conversion after filtering (though this 
>   post-filtering approach
>   is inferior to converting from sRGB prior to filtering).

So the spec won't guarantee you the ideal behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, most of the images are in sRGB space. And if you don't do any special processing when load image data into OpenGL or in the shader while rendering you'll get "wrong" image - you're applying linear computation on non linear data. It appears darker than it should be when you render such an image.

However, if you do conversion to linear space you should also convert final rendered image back to sRGB space, because usually monitors have 2.2 gamma curve applied (to be compatible with CRT output as it was before LCD screens).

So, you either do it manually in shader, or use sRGB extensions, which are provided both for textures (to convert from sRGB to linear) and frame buffers (to automatically convert back from linear to sRGB). To get correct image you should have both conversions applied.

Enabling gamma correction and doing it right gives more natural and softer image. Check out this article https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Gamma-Correction for more detailed explanation

Comment: I think you missed the question.